# EmEditor macro in JS: how to get the full content of a document object

Tags: javascript, macros, emeditor

To get the content of a document in EmEditor macros, it seems that the full content need to be selected first and then **Window.Document.Selection.Text** is used to get its content. But this would lose the current position and seletion status.

Is there something like **Window.Document.Content** to do the job in a better way? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You do need to select the entire document to get the content as a string. You can save the selection positions with `GetAnchorPointX`, `GetActivePointX`, and set the selection with `SetActivePoint`.

Comment: Thank you @MakotoE ! The workaround is ok, but it seems to be a big challenge to restore all the current selections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to get the content of the document in a macro by appending each line, like so:

```
var content = "";
numberOfLines = document.GetLines();
for ( i = 1; i <= numberOfLines; i++ ) {
    content = content + document.GetLine( i ) + "\r\n";
}
```

It will leave the cursor and all selections in place. But this method is slow if your file has more than hundreds of lines.

Comment: Thank you @Hans ! I just tested it with a file of 620000 lines, and the loop spent about 7 seconds, it's not bad. Good solution!

Comment: Great, Kaspa. The loop failed to catch the last line. I changed the condition `i < numberOfLines` into `i <= numberOfLines`.

Comment: @Kaspa: funcContent, what a good idea. I see I missed out on the newline characters as well. Added your `+ "\r\n"` to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Kaspa: by including the `document.GetLines()` into the for-condition it gets evaluated as many times as there are logical lines. That might slow it down a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your further comments!

Answer (score 0):

@Hans  Thank you for your further comments! Below is my codes for it:

```js
function funcContent() {
    var content = document.GetLine(1);
    for (i = 2; i < document.GetLines() + 1; i++) {
        content = content + "\r\n" + document.GetLine(i);
    }
    return content;
}
```